# Getting "numeric argument required" when running a script with arithmetic operations

Tags: shell, sh

I'm trying to write a function that is supposed to convert a time stamp of the form hr:min:sec,ms (i.e 15:41:47,757) to milliseconds. The function is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
mili () {

    hr=$(echo "$1" | cut -c1-2)
    echo "hr is: " $hr
    min=$(echo "$1" | cut -c4-5)
    echo "min is: " $min
    sec=$(echo "$1" | cut -c7-8)
    echo "sec is: " $sec
    ms=$(echo "$1" | cut -c10-12)
    echo "ms is: " $ms
    total=$(($hr \* 3600 + $min \* 60 + $sec) \* 1000 + $ms)

    return "$total"
    #echo "Result is: "$total" "
}

mili $1
```

However, when I run it:

```
./mili.sh "15:41:47,757"
```

I get the following output message:

```
./mili.sh: command substitution: line 15: syntax error near unexpected token 
`\*'
./mili.sh: command substitution: line 15: `($hr \* 3600 + $min \* 60 + $sec) 
\* 1000 + $ms'
./mili.sh: line 17: return: : numeric argument required
```

I've tried variations of expr with and without single quotes, double quotes, and backticks but can never seem to get it to compute the arithmetic. I can confirm a simple command like this works:  expr 2 * 3 but when I try to use something similar in my script it fails.

How can I get it to simply compute my expression?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use *mili* and not *milli* (as in [millisecond](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/millisecond#Noun))?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Inside arithmetic, `*` does not need to be escaped.  Also, some parentheses were missing.  Thus, replace:

```
total=$(($hr \* 3600 + $min \* 60 + $sec) \* 1000 + $ms)
```

With:

```
total=$((($hr * 3600 + $min * 60 + $sec) * 1000 + $ms))
```

#### Alternative

The code can be simplified avoiding the need for multiple calls to `cut`:

```
mili() {
    IFS=':,' read hr min sec ms <<<"$1"
    echo "hr is: " $hr
    echo "min is: " $min
    echo "sec is: " $sec
    echo "ms is: " $ms
    total=$((($hr * 3600 + $min * 60 + $sec) * 1000 + $ms))
    echo "Total=$total"
    return "$total"
}
```

#### Aside: Bash arithmetic and dollar signs

In a Bash arithmetic context, the dollar sign before a variable is optional.  For example:

```
$ a=1; echo "$((1 + a)) and $((1+ $a))"
2 and 2
```

While some style guides recommend omitting `$` in an arithmetic context, there is a key difference.  As [Chepner points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765276/getting-numeric-argument-required-when-running-script-with-arithmetic-operatio#comment78602768_45765439) in the comments, the treatment of undefined variables is very different:

```
$ unset a
$ echo $((1 + $a))
bash: 1 + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")
$ echo $((1 + a))
1
```

In summary:

1. If you want an undefined variable to default to zero, then omit the `$`.
2. If you want an undefined variable to be replace with nothing, possibly causing an invalid expression, then include the `$`.

In the shell function `mili`, an undefined variable `hr`, `min`, etc., would indicate a code error and we might want an error message to warn us about it and we would want to include the `$`.  In other circumstances where a default value of zero is reasonable, we would not and omitting the `$` would be correct.

Comment: Also, inside `$((...))` you can use variable names without `$` -- `total=$(( ((hr * 60 + min) * 60 + sec) * 1000 + ms ))` -- I find adding a spaces inside the double parentheses help readability.

Comment: Wow...Worked like a charm. Thanks man, really appreciate it. *facepalm*

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, you are right & many style guides prefer the removal of `$`.  (I would prefer it if bash was designed for notational consistency.)

Comment: There is an ever-so-subtle difference between using `$` and not: with `$`, the variable is expanded before the expression is evaluated. The empty string produced by an undefined variable will produce an invalid expression, or at least a different expression than you expected will be evaluated. Without the `$`, the string is assumed to be a variable *during* evaluation, with undefined variables defaulting to integer values of 0.

Comment: @chepner That is an excellent point!  I just added discussion of that to the answer.

Answer (score 15):

Another couple of points:

1. don't `return "$total"`: a return value is an int between 0 and 255. You need to `echo "$total"`
2. you're going to have errors when the hour/minute/second is `08` or `09` -- bash treats numbers with leading zero as octal, and 8 and 9 are invalid octal digits.

   ```
   $ mili 11:22:09,456
   hr is:  11
   min is:  22
   sec is:  09
   ms is:  456
   bash: (11 * 3600 + 22 * 60 + 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")
   ```

I'd write:

```
mili () {     
    IFS=":,." read -r hr min sec ms <<<"$1"
    echo "hr is:   $hr" >&2
    echo "min is:  $min" >&2
    echo "sec is:  $sec" >&2
    echo "ms is:  $ms" >&2
    echo "$(( ((10#$hr * 60 + 10#$min) * 60 + 10#$sec) * 1000 + 10#$ms ))"
}
```

where the `10#` forces base-10 numbers

then

```
$ ms=$(mili 11:22:09.456)
hr is:   11
min is:  22
sec is:  09
ms is:  456

$ echo $ms
40929456
```

Comment: Thank you for the valuable input! I was not aware of this.

Comment: `10#$hr` is clumsy. An alternative `${hr#0}` isn't any better. bash is not pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crazy alternative:

```
$ mili () {
    IFS=., read -r time ms <<<"$1"
    ms3=$(cut -c 1-3 <<<"${ms}000")
    echo "$(date -u -d "1970-01-01 $time" +%s)$ms3"
}

$ mili 15:41:47,757
56507757

$ mili 15:41:47,75
56507750

$ mili 15:41:47
56507000
```

Comment: I'd incorporate `$ms3` into the format string to avoid `echo` and a command substitution: `date -u -d "1970-01-01 $time" +"%s$ms3"`.